# URL is not loading after using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

The following code should open the given URL in the web browser. But it's not working after clicking button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="b">

  <button onclick="a()">Search</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function a(value) {
      var x = document.getElementById("b").value;
      var url = "";
      if (x.startsWith("http://")) {
        url = x;
      } else {
        url = "http://" + x;
      }
      window.open(url);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I get `Blocked opening '<URL>' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.` in my console

Comment: strings are immutable so you cant just say `url = x` you could try `url += x` or when you declare `url` leave it undefined and just say `var url;` so then it can be defined based on the logic you provided. check this out for the error https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox/ should be able to ad an attribute for it

Comment: Why are you using `function a(value)` if there is no use of `value`

Comment: There is a lot of scope for improvement, error checking and missing attributes.

Comment: @MichaelCacciano I'm a little confused by your comment. String immutability shouldn't matter here - he's not trying to access or change a piece of a string, he's trying to set it to a new value. Changing the value of a string variable after it's been declared is perfectly valid in javascript. Can you further explain and/or show an example of why it shouldn't work? I ran his exact code and it worked fine, other than the sandbox error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me....

Think you are using a pop up blocker and that's probably why you are nothing is happening when you click the button, disable all plugins on Chrome or Firefox browser...whichever you are using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="b">

  <button onclick="a()">Search</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function a(value) {
      var x = document.getElementById("b").value;
      var url = "";
      if (x.startsWith("http://")) {
        url = x;
      } else {
        url = "http://" + x;
      }
      window.open(url);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Try the code in pen... [demo link here](https://jsfiddle.net/magnusmel/2qp84cfk/1/#&togetherjs=ruk8Rp8isA)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="b">

  <button onclick="a()">Search</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function a(value) {
      var x = document.getElementById("b").value;
      var url = "";
      if (x !="") {
        url = x;
      }
      window.open("http://"+url);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

here is the link of code  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qedoRZ

you can fill `google.com` in to the input box then it open the `goole` home page.